# Strange error in openmp program

Tags: c, serialization, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a openmp code that is producing some strange error. Apparently the parallel version of the program is not processing the input data properly. I wrote the same program serially for comparing the output.
I am providing a code similar to my program here. I am clueless what is happening.

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include<omp.h>

            unsigned long long int N=100000;
            unsigned long long int *a1,*b1,*c1,*d1,*a2,*b2,*c2,*d2,*a3,*b3,*c3,*d3;

            void init(){ //just to put some random data

                unsigned long long int i;
                a1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                b1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                c1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                d1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));

                a2=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                b2=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                c2=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                d2=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));

                a3=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                b3=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                c3=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                d3=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a1[i]=rand();
                    a2[i]=a1[i];
                    a3[i]=a1[i];                    

                    b1[i]=rand();
                    b2[i]=b1[i];
                    b3[i]=b1[i];                    

                    c1[i]=rand();
                    c2[i]=c1[i];
                    c3[i]=c1[i];                    

                    d1[i]=rand();
                    d2[i]=d1[i];
                    d3[i]=d1[i];                    

                }
            }
            void seq(){//runs on one core 

                unsigned long long int i;

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a2[i]=a2[i]*b2[i];
                }

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    c2[i]=c2[i]*d2[i];
                }

            }
            void parallel(){//runs on 2 cores

                unsigned long long int i;

                #pragma omp parallel
                {
                    int ID;
                    ID=omp_get_thread_num();
                    if(ID==0){
                        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                            a3[i]=a3[i]*b3[i];
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                            c3[i]=c3[i]*d3[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            void main(){

                init();
                double time;
                int i;

                time=omp_get_wtime();
                seq();
                time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
                printf("\n time for serial execution : %f\n",time);

                time=omp_get_wtime();
                parallel();
                time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
                printf("\ntime for parallel execution : %f\n",time);
                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    if(a2[i]!=a3[i])
                        break;

                }

                if(i!=-1)
                    printf("|| error i: %d a1: %llu,a2: %llu,b2: %llua3: %llu,b3:%llu\n||",i,a1[i],a2[i],b2[i],a3[i],b3[i]);


            }
```

As you can see the parallel and the sequential code is operating on the same data and performs the same operations. Still, in some executions parallel code is producing the wrong output. The output from the serial code is always correct. Also I can not understand why the timing for parallel execution is worse than the serial execution.

Some results of execution are given below :
//----------------------------------execution 1--------------------
time for serial execution : 0.001207

time for parallel execution : 0.001949
|| error i: 1 a1: 1957747793,a2: 830551664052244655,b2: 424238335a3: 6241267121326981713,b3:424238335
//----------------------------------execution 2--------------------
 time for serial execution : 0.001241

time for parallel execution : 0.001386
|| error i: 1 a1: 1957747793,a2: 830551664052244655,b2: 424238335a3: 6241267121326981713,b3:424238335

Comment: Note: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: Can you illustrate please? Do you that is the reason for this problem here?

Comment: It is a note, not that it is likely the problem. Just don't.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have always used malloc like this(though I am not coding for long). Can you please tell the correct way?

Comment: I did tell you what to do. Just as general advice: **Never ever** cast if you don't know exactly **why** and you accept all its implications.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: You are declaring i outside the parallel block so the variable is shared between threads. Each thread must have its own i for the for loop. Either put i inside the omp parallel block or make it local to the for loop

Comment: The default rules make an exception to facilitate c89 parallel loop but it does promote  confusion

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, the variable "i" is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comments, I figured this out. The variable "i" was the problem here. Either we have to declare "i" inside the parallel block or declare "private(i)"